# How can I politely ask if I will be hired?

Tags: hiring

I have done a work experience for my master in this company for about 6 months and now my contract is going to end.
I have done interviews with other companies but my boss doesn't know it and some of them want to hire me.
Last week I also did an interview with my actual company's HR department, which went really well, and ended up with a lot of compliments but no contract.

How could I ask if they are going to hire me without looking disrespectful and arrogant?

EDIT: It is not the duplicate of [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p) as I already work in this company

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat the difference, significant one, is that OP is already working for the company he is interviewing with, and going to ask.

Comment: I wouldn't think it's inappropriate to approach your direct manager and ask if they know how long it'll take to get some feedback because you want to know whether you should start applying for positions elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No need to ask until you know you have other offer waiting

You work there already, so they have a strong reason to inform you and your boss about their decision. If they didn't, then either there is no decision or they don't want you to know it, for example to prevent loss of enthusiasm if they are planning to let you go. In both situations asking makes no sense, there is nothing to tell you or they don't want to do it. And you are not losing anything by not asking at this point.

Asking your boss / manager during  informal conversation shouldn't usually be a problem, but if you have a reason to believe he might see it as *"disrespectful and arrogant"*, then it might be safer not to do it. If these are *your* concerns, and your boss never gave you any reason for them, then don't worry about it too much.

Consider approaching him in an informal setting (like cafeteria) and asking something like this:

> Do you know how long it will take HR to give me some feedback?

or

> As you are aware, my contract ends in x time, and I had an interview in regards to this on x day, since I would very much like to continue working here. When can I expect an answer on the issue so I can plan ahead for next steps? *[wording by Leon](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93215/how-can-i-politely-ask-if-i-will-be-hired#comment276803_93220)*

That's it. Nothing rude, disrespectful or arrogant. Just signaling you are still waiting.

## If you have better job offer

Just take it, and inform your current company that you are no longer interested, thank you, it was great to work with you, good bye.

## If you have an acceptable job offer but would rather stay at your current company

This is the only time asking is something you have to do, even if your manager might be a bit over-sensitive about it or tries avoid this conversation. Inform your boss that you have another job offer, that you would prefer to stay with your current company but first things first, you need employment and this is the offer, you have X days to sign it so your current company needs to give you an offer in X-2 days (or earlier) for you to be  able to consider it. Ask your manager what he thinks  is the best course of action in this situation. Be calm, professional, don't accuse your company of being slow or anything. Just state the facts as you know them.

For example:

> Boss, I'm sorry but I need to know what the decision about my employment will be. I have other offers, I need to sign one of them before [insert date here] if I want it. I would prefer to stay here, but I can't afford the risk of not being employed neither here nor there, I hope you understand. Should I talk to HR? Or accept one of the other offers? Because if [current company] will not give me an offer before [insert a bit earlier date here] I won't have a choice, I will have to work for someone else. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my situation is the one where I'd like to stay but I can't wait too much. Could you help me to define a good way to approach my PM?

Comment: @Kiverick do you have another offer? If no, then continue looking. Practicing interviews can't hurt.

Comment: @Kiverick just aproach your manager or company's HR rep you talked to(whichever is responsible for your re-hire at this point) and kindly say:As you are aware my contract ends in x time and I had an interview in regards to this on x day since I would very much like to continue working here(as you say you do). When can I expect an answer on the issue so I can plan ahead for next steps?

Comment: @Mołot Yes I do have other offers

Comment: @Kiverick You might want to wait a bit before accepting. What if someone else has better advice, but now will not post it, seeing you accepted mine? I mean, I appreciate acceptance mark, I just want you to get all help you possibly can.

Comment: The problem with waiting until you have an offer is that the offer might expire in three days, and your company says "We'd love to hire you, but it will take us a week to process the paperwork."

Comment: I disagree that you shouldn't say anything. It's completely reasonable to want to know if you'll still have a job after your original end date. Especially if the hiring process is slow, then you need to start bugging them far in advance. Just couch it in excitement to stay with the company: "I really want to stay here, but I can't wait until the end of my contract to plan my employment.   Is there a plan to offer me permanent employment?" If you already work there, they may not see any urgency.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer will depend strongly on the country and culture of the employer.

For the USA, typically, a contractor asking an existing employer if there is a strong possibility of an extension of contract or a full time employment offer is appropriate.

Unfortunately, you may not receive a timely answer. As a hiring manager, I may wish to extend an employment offer, but need approval and budget from the company before this can occur-- I have had instances where it takes more than a year to have the budget to hire. I have also supported contractors job search when I know we cannot offer them an extension of position.